# New Domain Registration - Price differences

Tags: domain-registration

I need to register new domain name. I gone through many sites. All sites are showing different prices. Lowest price (99/- Rs) I found on http://www.bigrock.in/. On other sites, like GoDaddy or rackspace, its showing more than 600/- Rs.

Why are these price differences? Are there any differences in services, up time, security? Is it safe to register at bigrock?

Comment: Is R for Rupee or for Rand?

Comment: Yes, R is for Indian Rupee.

Comment: 99 Rupee -> 1.7 USD and 600 Rupee -> 10.8 USD

Answer (score 4):

For a lot of the smaller companies (us included) we are just resellers for a Registrar (in our case NetEarthOne). Registrars often offer different pricing bands depending on the volume of domains you purchase from them and then resell via your site.

As we are low volume, we pay more than other higher volume resellers but we don't add any mark-up on our cost price so often our domains are actually cheaper than some of the larger companies for example Fasthosts.

It is the same as many businesses, the big Registrars can buy in bulk, keeping prices down low and then the middlemen (us) can either sell at cost or try to make a small profit. Those resellers buying/selling more can leverage cheaper prices which they *can* then pass on to their customers. There can be several layers of Resellers as well which can push the price up or and extra layers of obfuscation which can hamper when trying to make changes to your domain.

Some companies also sell domains below cost or free as a loss-leader to try and get the business in. Same as your supermarket selling the bread & milk cheap to get you through the door.

You should be looking to see what additional features their dolman registration provides. Do they have a control panel where you can change the nameservers or update your contact details? Do they offer domain privacy whereby your details are hidden by a front company e.g. PrivacyProtect.org so spammers can't harvest your email address from a whois lookup. Do they allow free transfers out and can you run this process from your control panel?

Is it better to go with a big name? I don't know. Ok they are well known so you "should" be in safer hands but as Lèse majesté says, even the big names can be underhand. Everyone will have a customer service horror story they can tell you about company X, Y or Z. The little guy can often provide a better price & service and you will end up building a good relationship with them which can help when it comes to requiring additional services or needing advice.

Not really much of an answer, more of a ramble but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest difference between registrars is the type of company you deal with. For most people, a domain registrar is just a company through which they create a record in the domain name registry for the TLD they've selected. That means that domain registration services are essentially a [commodity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodity) in 99% of cases.

However, for whatever reason, the domain name industry has attracted unethical businesses and corruption almost from the very start (look into the history of InterNIC and Network Solutions). And even though practices like [frontrunning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_front_running) are technically illegal and supposedly wiped out when [domain tasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_tasting) was eliminated, you're still dealing with potentially sketchy companies in a position of trust.

So it's not so much what benefits a good registrar can provide for you so much as what a bad registrar can do to hurt you. For instance, a lot of registrars are closely associated with domain squatters/speculators (or may even be the same company, as in the case of Godaddy's domain warehousing scandal). You may or may not care if your registrar tells domain squatters or your competitors when your domain is due to expire, or the fact that they hijack expired domains for free advertising, or the fact that companies like Godaddy have long been a safe-haven for spammers, but some of the worst registrars have been implicated in things like credit card fraud and domain theft. The domain name industry is largely self-policing, so is it worth the risk to do business with a shady company?

That said, sleazy business practices are pretty much the norm in the domain name industry. So *never* be late renewing your domain. At best, you'll have to spend hundreds of dollars to reclaim it, at worst, your registrar could turn it into a neon billboard for your competitors or you could lose the domain altogether.

What I recommend doing is to just take advantage of the free domain that most hosting packages come with. And don't register a domain with a company that charges you for things like private registration. Aside from that, there's not much else to choose between.

Answer (score 1):

That website says they are an ICANN registrar, which is exactly what Go Daddy is. It really comes down to preference where you buy from. I work at a company and we resell domains through Enom (another big ICANN registrar) and people buy from us because they like to support local businesses or because it's easier for us to help them manage the domain when they have questions.

I don't like Go Daddy but that is just my opinion. You can always transfer the domain to another registrar after it's been registered for 60.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to make a clear distinction between domain creation/registration
 and website hosting.
Most (if not all) webhosters offers domain names registration services.
There is a huge bet and but on this point.
A number of Webhosters want to hold people hostage on their hosting services,
years after years.

A true domain registrar services should just offer the service
 of registering a name with ICANN which assume they offer temporary parking
 of your new domain name on their server.
This until you decide which hoster best fit your needs.

We assume that you invent a specific name (or acronym) which do not exist on the web.
This is different from buying a name already owned by a speculator 
himself waiting for a real user (like you)to buy it from him.
Another point relates to companies who want to force the sale of other 
services with the domain name.
My final point is to tell about a consistent naming of your services to be delivered on the web.This may imply a multiname strategy,hence several domain names which will lead to a single master web site.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise Godaddy and Enom as domain registars.Don't choose Network Solutions and Tucows as their prices are really high.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present a counter argument that cheapest isn't always the best. There are many stories of cheap registrars that give poor service or do offer only a limited amount of services. Price wise, it's better to find a registrar that is kind of a one-stop shop for things that are important beyond just domain registration.

One thing to look out for is a registrar that can help register domains for your company in a targeted country.

For example, specific countries need proof of local business or address. Some registrars offer **Trustee Services** where they provide assistance in registering said domain name using their local presence (usually lawyers or businesses operating for the registrar. Some countries require **trademark registration** prior to domain name registration.

A registrar with an all-in-one service, such as one that can also purchase certificates and send domain expiry reminders, is a service that can help your business in the long-term.

**Also important:** look for a company that is transparent with fees in every step that they have. Nobody wants to be thinking they only need to pay a minimal fee, only to realize after their purchase that the recurring monthly or annual fee is actually bigger than what they initially thought. A lot of shady/cheap registrars operate that way.

Answer (score -1):

I highly suggest you register at Godaddy for $7.49 or change that to R's, using http://instantdomainsearch.com/ . You can manage your domains and many things.

I've never heard of bigrock.

my 2 cents

Comment: What are the differences of registering domain with different provider? I know that registering for hosting makes difference but not sure about regestering for domain name.

Comment: Not going to -1, but I don't think it really addresses the core question of what is the difference between different domain registrars?   Is it like salt where it's just the same stuff sold by different companies?  Or is it like wine where there's a big difference between who makes it?

Comment: there aren't any differences, just Godaddy focuses on their domain services a lot and they have many tools. I'm just speaking from experience. take it or leave it.