# Where is the best place to buy domain names and how much should I pay?

Tags: domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Domain Registration - Price differences](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/new-domain-registration-price-differences)

I want to buy a domain name.  I plan to set up my own A, NS, and MX records using Slicehost.   So I guess I just need the cheapest place, right?

How much I should be paying for .com or .org?

Comment: Perhaps my question was not very focused.  But I don't really think my question from the title, 'where should I buy a cheap domain name?' is duplicated by the above question or by any other questions I can find.  Happily I got a few good answers before this was closed.

Comment: I bought my domain from namecheap.com for about $9 I think.  So far so good, I guess.  1&1 was cheaper, but only for the first year and it seems like commenters on life hacker highly recommended namecheap so I went with that.

Comment: If you want a premium domain name, you should try a premium domain names marketplace like https://www.oneclickname.com/

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what top-level domain you are purchasing.

For .com, 8-10 dollars is a reasonable price for a year.

You want to look for a place that will let you easily change your DNS records.

I have personally used Namecheap.

In an effort to avoid a flame war, I would like to cite a [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5683682/five-best-domain-name-registrars) which listed the five best domain registrars according to its readers.

1. [Namecheap](http://www.namecheap.com/)
2. [1&1](http://order.1and1.com/)
3. [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/)
4. [Name.com](http://www.name.com/)
5. [Gandi](http://www.gandi.net/)